# 2 services with same CIDR

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have a problem where I'm trying to route web traffic to a phpfpm instance. Periodically, when I restart my aws ec2 instances, I get 502 'bad gateway' errors because the phpfpm container isn't responding from the web service container.

I can jump into the php container no problem and everything seems fine with it, but somehow i can't do `telnet phpcontainer 9000` - it says the connection could not be established. it seems to be resolving the ip of the service name to the service gateway ok.  The php service only has 1 replica but the web service has 2 replicas (global replication).

Then I starting checking all the ip addresses of the services and containers.

I noticed that 2 services have the same cidr (the very service with the problem):

```
docker service inspect webservice | grep Addr
                    "Addr": "10.255.0.4/16"
                    "Addr": "172.20.0.2/16"
docker service inspect phpservice23 | grep Addr
                    "Addr": "172.20.0.2/16"
```

Is this normal?

All the ip addresses are unique though (note that above i'm talking about the **service cidrs**)

I just cannot figureout what is causing this 1 particular container to be inaccessible from another service.

If I restart the problem container, it will work after that.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's a bug with the overlay networking. There are a fair number of reports in the github issues. Make sure you are running the latest release and search the issues to see if you can find a matching scenario.

Comment: ahhhh thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually learned that the problem here was that we were creating services via the api with a bad spec. There may be another bug at play, but if you create a service and do not specify the `EndpointSpec.Mode` property, then we got services that would get duplicate ip addresses when the docker daemon is restarted.